# Creating a constructor containing 2D array

Tags: java

I'm making a java game that requires a board. I'm using an MVC pattern with 3 model classes. The first class is for one object and the second class is used for the board. I'm having some trouble making the constructor for this class that creates a 2d array of the objects that should be null. A later method will store objects within the array.

```
public Board(int rows, int columns) {
    objects = new Object [rows][columns];
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
        objects[r][c] = new Object();
```

This is part of my code. I have 3 private instance fields declared earlier in the class for rows, columns, and the 2d array of objects. Am I on the right track? I'm a little confused on how to make the objects null. Also, do I have to add this.rows = rows; and this.columns= columns; or something in this constructor? I hope this makes sense i'm new to java.

Comment: Settings objects to null is easy: `objects[r][c] = null`

Comment: @Cardinal-ReinstateMonica Thanks I appreciate the help!! Do you know if the rest of what I have is okay?

Comment: Should be. What does the rest of your class look? Is the `objects` field an object array (`Object[]`)?

Comment: @Cardinal-ReinstateMonica Yes it's private Object [][] objects;

Comment: "Also, do I have to add this.rows = rows; and this.columns= columns; or something in this constructor?" You have to set up *the fields that your class defines*. They may or may not have any particular relationship to the parameters of your constructor. You probably don't need to store these values separately, since you could always just measure the array later (using the `.length`).

Answer (score 0):

If your instances are named rows and columns, then yes, you have to do this.rows= rows and this.columns=columns if you want to store those values. Someone already answered the null question, so I'll skip that.

Comment: Thanks!! I figured I had to include that part. When I'm writing the setter method to store the objects would I approach it the same way with the this.rows/columns? Also, I would have to include another for loop to store the objects right?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to initialise your `objects` array with nulls.
The `new Object [rows][columns];` statement will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks! So instead of objects[r][c] = null;. I could just do objects[r][c]; since it's already null by default or would it not matter either way?